# Is there a way to control an iPad with an arduino?

Tags: ipad, arduino

I searched online, How to control an arduino with an iPad.

I want to push a button on my arduino and have an iPad play a video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand side you can implement a HID-compatible bluetooth profile and control your ipad in general, on the other hand side you can implement a more specific and custom iOS application which uses BLE (or SPP) profiles in Objective-C.

Comment: For example Sparkfun distribute a bluetooth module ("SparkFun Bluetooth Modem - BlueSMiRF HID") with a Roving Networks RN-42 chip with HID firmware, that can be used as a wireless joystick, mouse or keyboard. Further information such as code examples and the chip documentation are linked on the Sparkfun page: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10938